# MSM and EE question (subdomain using main domain's templates)

Tags: multi-site-manager, subdomain

I have recently installed MSM on my EE build. Both are the very latest. I followed the tutorial all the way through: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/install.html

When i visit the subdomain on my local host it shows up fine in terms of the styles being there however when I make an edit to a template via the control panel/or text editor it does not show up on the subdomain. I have all my templates saved out as files. If i edit the index page for the main site, it shows up on both the main and subdomain.

my main site is located in a public_html folder on my computer and at the same level is the subdomain folder named appropriately.  I am sorry my question is so high level. I bet I am just missing something obvious.

PS I have added an htaccess file to my subdomain folder with no success. This is all on apache on my local computer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the path to your template files is correct in your control panel. Look under Design > Templates > Global Preferences and check "Server path to site's templates"

Answer (score 0):

I have approached this by embedding a template to another site as documented here:

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/sites/code.html

```
{embed="site_short_name:template_group/template"}
```

I have actually done this for embedding entire templates.

Have you tried this approach? How did you copy all of your templates over when you setup the new Site?